# Fatal error: Cannot declare class InterdraftFactuursturen, because the name is already in use in

Tags: php, wordpress, class, plugins

I'm coding my first Wordpress plugin and I need to use a separate class which exists in the fsnl_api.class.php file. But no matter what I do I always get the following error message:

Fatal error: Cannot declare class InterdraftFactuursturen, because the name is already in use in

There is no other class with the same name, but when I refer to that file I always get that error. Hereunder you'll see a bit of the code in the main file. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening? I'm searching for hours right now to find a solution and I'm getting desperate and frustrated.

```
require_once('fsnl_api.class.php');

if (!function_exists('add_action')) {
    echo "You can't access this file!";
    exit;
}

class InterdraftFactuursturen {
    function __construct() {
        add_action('init', array($this, 'custom_post_type'));
    }

// some functions
}

if (class_exists('InterdraftFactuursturen')) {
    $interdraftFactuursturen = new InterdraftFactuursturen();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($interdraftFactuursturen, 'activate') );

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, array($interdraftFactuursturen, 'deactivate') );
```

The fsnl_api.class.php class

```
class fsnl_api
{
    protected $url;
    protected $verb;
    protected $requestBody;
    protected $requestLength;
    protected $username;
    protected $password;
    protected $acceptType;
    protected $responseBody;
    protected $responseInfo;
    
    public function __construct ($url = null, $verb = 'GET', $requestBody = null)
    {
        $this->url              = $url;
        $this->verb             = $verb;
        $this->requestBody      = $requestBody;
        $this->requestLength    = 0;
        $this->username         = null;
        $this->password         = null;
        $this->acceptType       = 'application/json';
        $this->responseBody     = null;
        $this->responseInfo     = null;
        
        if ($this->requestBody !== null)
        {
            $this->buildPostBody();
        }
    }
    
    public function flush ()
    {
        $this->requestBody      = null;
        $this->requestLength    = 0;
        $this->verb             = 'GET';
        $this->responseBody     = null;
        $this->responseInfo     = null;
    }
    
    public function execute ()
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        $this->setAuth($ch);
        
        try
        {
            switch (strtoupper($this->verb))
            {
                case 'GET':
                    $this->executeGet($ch);
                    break;
                case 'POST':
                    $this->executePost($ch);
                    break;
                case 'PUT':
                    $this->executePut($ch);
                    break;
                case 'DELETE':
                    $this->executeDelete($ch);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Current verb (' . $this->verb . ') is an invalid REST verb.');
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidArgumentException $e)
        {
            curl_close($ch);
            throw $e;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            curl_close($ch);
            throw $e;
        }
        
    }
    
    public function buildPostBody ($data = null)
    {
        $data = ($data !== null) ? $data : $this->requestBody;
        
        if (!is_array($data))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid data input for postBody.  Array expected');
        }
        
        $data = http_build_query($data, '', '&');
        $this->requestBody = $data;
    }
    
    protected function executeGet ($ch)
    {       
        $this->doExecute($ch);  
    }
    
    protected function executePost ($ch)
    {
        if (!is_string($this->requestBody))
        {
            $this->buildPostBody();
        }
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->requestBody);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        
        $this->doExecute($ch);  
    }
    
    protected function executePut ($ch)
    {
        if (!is_string($this->requestBody))
        {
            $this->buildPostBody();
        }
        
        $this->requestLength = strlen($this->requestBody);

        $fh = fopen('php://memory', 'rw');
        fwrite($fh, $this->requestBody);
        rewind($fh);
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $this->requestLength);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);

        $this->doExecute($ch);
        
        fclose($fh);
    }
    
    protected function executeDelete ($ch)
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
        
        $this->doExecute($ch);
    }
    
    protected function doExecute (&$curlHandle)
    {
        $this->setCurlOpts($curlHandle);
        $this->responseBody = curl_exec($curlHandle);
        $this->responseInfo = curl_getinfo($curlHandle);
        
        curl_close($curlHandle);
    }
    
    protected function setCurlOpts (&$curlHandle)
    {
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: ' . $this->acceptType));
    }
    
    protected function setAuth (&$curlHandle)
    {
        if ($this->username !== null && $this->password !== null)
        {
            curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
            curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->username . ':' . $this->password);
        }
    }
    
    public function getAcceptType ()
    {
        return $this->acceptType;
    } 
    
    public function setAcceptType ($acceptType)
    {
        $this->acceptType = $acceptType;
    } 
    
    public function getPassword ()
    {
        return $this->password;
    } 
    
    public function setPassword ($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    } 
    
    public function getResponseBody ()
    {
        return $this->responseBody;
    } 
    
    public function getResponseInfo ()
    {
        return $this->responseInfo;
    } 
    
    public function getUrl ()
    {
        return $this->url;
    } 
    
    public function setUrl ($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;
    } 
    
    public function getUsername ()
    {
        return $this->username;
    } 
    
    public function setUsername ($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    } 
    
    public function getVerb ()
    {
        return $this->verb;
    } 
    
    public function setVerb ($verb)
    {
        $this->verb = $verb;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please share the contents of your fsnl_api.class.php file so wr can have a look.

Comment: It ain't my class but I added it to my post

Answer (score 0):

Try to use diffrent name or namespace this class.
May be somewhere in Wordpress this class exists.

I would recommend you for the future, when you create own class to always namespace Your class. It is a good practice to namespace your own classes.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

You can namespace your class for example (if you really want to have all in one file) like below:

```
namespace YourPluginName {
    class InterdraftFactuursturen {
        // Code
    }
}

namespace {
        $interdraftFactuursturen = new YourPluginName\InterdraftFactuursturen();   
}
```

But I would recommend to store your class namespaced in other file then import by using require_once.

Check [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)  for more informations.

Comment: I did both and I still keep getting the error. But thanks for the info about namespaces that's nice to know.

Comment: Try to just remove add_action in InterdraftFactuursturen in _construct. And check if this something changed